# css: изменение свойств родителя в зависимости от состояния потомка

Tags: html, css, css3, css-selectors

Подскажите, позволяет ли CSS изменить свойства родителя в зависимости от состояния потомка (к примеру есть фокус или нет фокуса)

например, изменить задний фон, если у дочернего элемента установлен фокус

что-то типа такого:

```
.parent(input:focus) {
    background: red;
}
```

у меня задача - перекрасить границу (`border`), если установлен фокус в элемент `input`, который находится внутри контейнера с данной рамкой

Конечно я могу сделать через )*(:

1. контейнер с рамкой сам по себе
2. перед ним элемент `input` сам по себе и через абсолютное позиционирование этот элемент находится как бы в рамке
3. а дальше `input:focus ~ .parent {}`

Но это все таки изврат и не хотелось бы использовать такой подход
Позволяет ли css решать подобные задачи более аккуратно?

Comment: Изврат - это когда дети диктуют родителям. Делайте выводы - можно или нет.

Comment: @UModeL, но в данном случае не дети изменяют свойства родителя, а родитель изменяет свои свойства в зависимости от свойств детей

в обычных языках для этого есть `if`, но в css такого нет :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На текущий момент (сентябрь 2020г.), реализация поведения описанного в вопросе, используя только CSS - **недоступна**.

Ждём, когда [утвердят и добавят](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#has-pseudo) псевдокласс `:has()`. [Следим](https://caniuse.com/css-has) и надеемся.

Пока решения два: пересмотреть разметку или использовать скрипты.